# Azure RDP Login Error

Tags: azure

### I created a AX 2012 R3 DEMO Environment in the AZURE. I am trying to login into the RDP but not able to Login. And get the error as:

### Remote Desktop Connection

Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
2) The remote computer is turned off
3) The remote computer is not available on the network

### Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.

### OK   Help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure connecting to the RDP port isn't being blocked by your firewall (possibly port 3389)
  -This is a common problem
  -You can see what PORTS are being used by going to the Azure Portal -> Virtual Machines -> Endpoints
Also make sure the VM is turned on :)